# How to quickly tell if an SE site is out of beta?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, beta-sites

All sites are apparently listed [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) without any distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the list on that page, the icons on the left are the Release sites; on the right are Beta sites. Notice the similarity between all the Beta site icons:

[image]

Comment: this is very easy to tell. Can you or someone confirm that all "custom" icons are non-beta and all white-and-blue standard icons are beta?

Comment: @Louis. It is easy to confirm. If the site is still listed on [Area 51](area51.stackexchange.com) it's in Beta, if not, it's out of beta. The sketchy icon and look & feel is a trademark of all Beta sites.

Comment: @Louis Yup, what Diago said; You can click on all the sites with the icons with the blue checkered background and verify that they are all, in fact, Beta sites. Then click the rest and see that they are not. Once you verify that fact, you can then just use the icon to quickly see which is what.

Answer (score 2):

It's got real graphics and the non-beta look.

> The beta site is set up with a
>   temporary URL and a temporary design.
>   The site name and final design will be
>   chosen when the beta period ends.

-- http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

As of the time of this writing the beta design always looks like:
[image]

Easy to spot quickly.

Comment: how to tell that?

Comment: To quickly tell like your question asks, use this example: look at this  http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ and then this http://askubuntu.com/home  At the time of this writing the first is in beta (the beta look in the sample I showed above), the second is not in beta (has a custom design).